# CMS for easy administration and Client uploads

Tags: content-management-system

A charity has asked for my opinion on what CMS to use for a new website. A couple of web developers have donated their time to develop the website.

What is need is the following.
Easy uploads of images / video's  The client must be able to upload video's and images of events that they are coordinating. The client is not tech savvy, and this is the most important thing.

Easy to medium administration. The site is to be administered and supported by a new person who is willing to learn what they need to.

Easy access to make donations.

I nice, clean look. (this is really up to the developer though)

Any advice would be appreciated.  After research, the three candidates seem to be Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla, and views on these or other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for Wordpress. It's probably the easiest for non tech savvy users.